# How to calculate the unrealised profit on sinkable bond

Tags: bond

How is calculate the unrealised profit on Sinkable Bond when 50% of the bond value already been paid?

Is the following method correct:
Unrealised P&L = ((Current.Position * Market.Price) - Cost.of.the.Position) * Factor

The Factor is the remaining value of the Bond (100% - Repayments in %).

Thanks